# serialize concurent operations using resources

Tags: javascript, async-await

I have a list of operations. Each operation uses one resource. Some operations use the same resource.
For example op1 uses the same resource as op3.
symbolic code:

```
operations=[op1,op2,op3,op4,op5]
for (let i=0;i<operations.length;i++) {
  perform(operations[i])
}
```

fails because op1 and op3 uses the same resource. 
So another aproach:

```
operations=[op1,op2,op3,op4,op5]
for (let i=0;i<operations.length;i++) {
  await perform(operations[i])
}
```

does not fail, but op2 unnecessary waits for o1 to be finished even though they don't use the same resource.

other approach:

```
operations=[op1,op2,op3,op4,op5]
for (let i=0;i<operations.length;i++) {
  await operations[i].usedResource.isAvailable;
  perform(operations[i])
}
```

OK, op1 runs, op2 runs, op3 waits for resource blocked by op1,... but op4 and op5 waits as well for no reason.

Any ideas?

Comment: Create a todo-list. Iterate over the entire list and start all operations where all dependencies are available *(keep track of available and used dependencies)*, then remove these items from the todo list. When a task is done, make its used dependencies available and again, iterate over the entire list and start all operations where all dependencies are available, and so on ...  It's most likely that this time it will be only a single operations you'll start, but who knows. rince and repeat, untill the todo-list is empty and no tasks are running.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

Note - this code can be written in a more optimized way. this is just to give an idea.

```js
let operation = (operation, time) => () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            resolve();
        }, time);
    });
};

let op1 = operation("op1", 10000);

let op2 = operation("op2", 2000);

let op3 = operation("op3", 2000);

let op4 = operation("op4", 1000);

let op5 = operation("op5", 5000);

const operations = [
    {name: "op1", operation: op1, resource: "R1", startedAt: 0},
    {name: "op2", operation: op2, resource: "R2", startedAt: 0},
    {name: "op3", operation: op3, resource: "R1", startedAt: 0},
    {name: "op4", operation: op4, resource: "R4", startedAt: 0},
    {name: "op5", operation: op5, resource: "R5", startedAt: 0}
];

let resources = {
    "R1": {
        isAvailable: true,
        queue: []
    },
    "R2": {
        isAvailable: true,
        queue: []
    },
    "R3": {
        isAvailable: true,
        queue: []
    },
    "R4": {
        isAvailable: true,
        queue: []
    },
    "R5": {
        isAvailable: true,
        queue: []
    },
};

async function operationExecutor(operation) {
    if (operation.startedAt === 0) {
        operation.startedAt = performance.now();
    }
    if (!resources[operation.resource].isAvailable) {
        console.log("Operation", operation.name, "waiting for Resource", operation.resource);
        resources[operation.resource].queue.push(operation);
    } else {
        console.log("Operation Started", operation.name);
        resources[operation.resource].isAvailable = false;
        console.log("Resource locked", operation.resource);
        await operation.operation();
        const t1 = performance.now();
        console.log("Resource released", operation.resource);
        resources[operation.resource].isAvailable = true;
        console.log("Operation Completed", operation.name, `in ${(t1 - operation.startedAt).toFixed(2)} milliseconds`);

        if (Array.isArray(resources[operation.resource].queue) && resources[operation.resource].queue.length > 0) {
            operationExecutor(resources[operation.resource].queue.splice(0, 1)[0]);
        }
    }
}

for (let i = 0; i < operations.length; i++) {
    (operationExecutor)(operations[i]);
}
```

Comment: What's with that `setTimeout` in an `async function`?

Comment: For the first one?

Comment: I mean in the second snippet. I can't see any use of the `setTimeout(…, 0)`, and in general async callbacks should be avoided in promise code. (The one in `operation` is fine)

Comment: yeah, `setTimeout(..., 0)` is not required. I can simply call it without await like `operationExecutor(resources[operation.resource].queue.splice(0, 1)[0]);`. Such that the control for the current operation can come out of the operationExecutor function. If I add await then the current operation needs to wait to come out until the queue gets empty

Answer (score 1):

Given these operations don't depend on each other's results, you can just make concurrent queues per resource and then run the operations in each sequentially:

```
const opsByResource = new Map()
for (const op in operations) {
    const r = op.usedResource
    if (!opsByResource.has(r)) opsByResource.put(r, [])
    opsByResource.get(r).push(op)
}

return Promise.all(Array.from(opsByResource, async ([res, ops]) => {
    for (const op in ops)
        await perform(op)
    console.log("Done with all operations on", res)
}))
```

Comment: Using `Promise.all`, If anyone of the operation fails. It will fail all other independent operations. right?

Comment: @Abhishek No, there is no cancellation in promises. It will only fail the resulting promise returned by `Promise.all`. Of course you can also use `Promise.allSettled` if you are interested in individual outcomes per resource. Or you might just want to catch exceptions inside the individual loop iterations, and continue with the next operation after a failure. Or something else...

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by your solutions I have make it this way:

- Each resource keeps queue of locks (promises).
- In perform function I pop first lock from the queue and push my lock (promise) at the end.
- Then await for the first lock, perform operation and resolve my lock

I'm widely using my implementation of controlled promise, which is regullar promise with exposed "resolveTo" function and with option of auto-resolving after specified timeout. I'm wondering if anybody uses something similar, I personally cannot imagine programming without it.